# Is there a word for "unrealistically expecting immediate results"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was trying to describe my friend as being someone who gets upset in the absence of immediate gratification, but couldn't think of a good word.  A good example would be someone who comes back from the gym and takes off their shirt expecting to look fit after one session.

Is there a word to describe someone that does this?  The closest I could think of was "impatient", but that doesn't quite pin down the meaning.

Comment: How about two words...unrealistic expectations?

Comment: unrealistic expectations could also connote that the goal is not attainable... I'm looking for a word that has a more immediate connotation.  I think you did lead me to a word that I think works though!

Comment: "Someone who comes back from the gym and takes off their shirt expecting to look fit after one session" lacks patience, in other words, is impatient.

Answer (score 2):

After reading through some possibilities and some great suggestions, the word that I was led to is the compound adjective ***over-expectant***.  It more refers to the immediate situation the gym-goer is in.